# XMPP, Strophe and raw/stream data channels

Tags: json, performance, xmpp, strophe

I was using a jquery plugin to talk with bosh:
https://github.com/maxpowel/jQuery-XMPP-plugin

I read that i can use strophe to send data in stream mode, in order to save bandwidth.

What i need to have:

1. One normal channel where i exchange commands between chat computer users
2. Several channels to send not formatted data, but with the smallest amount of information, because the time of each message can round between 100ms

I've made a graph for better understanding.

[image: graph with explanation for better understanding]

How to do this with Strophe?

Second question is that i read about this json plugin for strophe http://code.google.com/p/prosody-modules/wiki/mod_json_streams .

Do you have already tried this? Is it stable and gives really a good win in bandwidth?

Thanks for your answer.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your second question, thats just an april fool joke (note the date it was published), and also, the XEP 0295 that the page references make that clear:

> NOTICE: This document is Humorous. It MAY provide amusement but SHOULD
>   NOT be taken seriously.

Comment: Yes. Now i've read with very attention that i understand your answer :) Thanks